# How to download a file via an ActionResult method?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-framework-version, actionresult, filecontentresult

I have this controller endpoint where an form can be submitted, and
and in case a specific form is being is being used it should "autodownload" a file generated based on the input provided from the user.

How do I go about this?

I have tried this

```
  public ActionResult SubmitForm()
  {
     if(specificForm)
     {
        byte[] file = GenerateFile(Request)
        return File(file, "application/x-pkcs7-certificates", "cer.p7b");
     }
     ...
     return ()
     
  }
```

but no download seem to start, I assume its because the controller force it to be an action result rather than a FilecontentResult?

How do I go about this?

Comment: ActionResult is just base class for all "Results". How do you call this method from client?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but it is called from a form => button press 
that calls a post ´call with the required information. 

I have we monkey debugging deduced that the method does return at the file and no further.

Comment: if you submit form from javascript (not just with button type "submit") then there are few cases where file will not be downloaded

Comment: @YegorAndrosov The response from the api call contains 
content-disposition: attachment; filename=cert.p7b
meaning the correct response is being performed. 
But no autodownload is started..

Comment: it looks like once the it has received a 200 response it is being redirected to another page by something -  not sure whether that should affect it, since it has already returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the site was being redirected to another page.
Which caused the response to never reach the user